# How can I expand the macro in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, armv8

```
.macro f x,y
    ...
.endm
....
    f x10,x11
```

How can I expand the usage of macro `f x10,x11`? `gcc -E` doesn't seem to help, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from your mention of gcc that you are using the GNU assembler, you can generate a listing file containing `.macro` expansions.  It's not mentioned in [the manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/a.html) but does show up in `as --help`:

```
  -a[sub-option...]   turn on listings
                          Sub-options [default hls]:
                          c      omit false conditionals
                          d      omit debugging directives
                          g      include general info
                          h      include high-level source
                          l      include assembly
                          m      include macro expansions
                          n      omit forms processing
                          s      include symbols
                          =FILE  list to FILE (must be last sub-option)
```

It would seem like `-am` would be what you want, but in fact that produces an empty listing file.  However, `-alm` does work.

So if your source code is

```
    .macro square dst, src
    mul \dst, \src, \src
    .endm
    
    square x0, x1
```

you can do

```
as -alm=foo.lst foo.s
```

and get the following in `foo.lst`:

```
AARCH64 GAS  foo.s          page 1


   1                        .macro square dst, src
   2                        mul \dst, \src, \src
   3                        .endm
   4                        
   5                        square x0, x1
   5 0000 207C019B  >  mul x0,x1,x1
   6
```

The macro expansion is shown on line 5.

---

Regarding your comment about `gcc -E`, it helps to understand that the GNU toolchain provides two entirely separate and independent ways to use macros in assembly:

- You can pass the source through the C preprocessor before feeding it to the assembler.  This allows you to use `#define` style macros, as in Frant's answer.  You can do both passes automatically by naming your file like `foo.S` with a capital S, and using `gcc` to assemble it, like `gcc -c foo.S`.
- The `.macro` style macros are processed by the assembler itself, and have nothing to do with the C preprocessor.  That's why `gcc -E` didn't have any effect.